# Android Connection with MYSQL database using php

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, networkonmainthread, jsonexception

I am trying to connect my Android login page with MySQL database present on the server.

But I am facing problem now in passing php file through Android. My connection from PHP to MySQL database is successful, though.

PHP code:

```
<?php
    $host='localhost';
    $uname='amodbina0106';
    $pwd='Amodbina200';
    $db="kezin_king";

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","amodbina0106","Amodbina200","kezin_king");
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "Connection Successful";


    $username = $_GET['username'];
    $password = $_GET['password'];
    $flag['code']=0;

    if($name == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == ''){
        echo 'please fill all values';
    }
    else{



        $sql=mysql_query("insert into sample values('$id','$name') ",$con);

        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))

        {
            $flag['code']=1;
            echo"hi";
        }

        print(json_encode($flag));
        mysql_close($con);
    }
?>
```

The output after running the php file on web browser is:

> Connection Successful please fill all values

My MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.nupur.phpdb_con;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText etUsername, etPassword;
    TextView txtView;
    Button btnLogin;
    String username;
    String password;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    String line = null;
    int code;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader reader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                insert();


                // txtView.setText(etUsername.getText()+" "+etPassword.getText());


            }
        });


    }

    public String insert() {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", password));
        try {

            // create HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

            // make GET request to the given URL
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(new         HttpGet("http://kezinking.com/SampleConLogin"));

            // receive response as inputStream
            inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

            // convert inputstream to string
            if (inputStream != null) {
                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    result += line;

                inputStream.close();
                return result;
            } else
                result = "Did not work!";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader
                    (new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
            Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
        }
        try {
            JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
            code = (json_data.getInt("code"));
            if (code == 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());

        }

        return null;
    }

   // @Override
    //public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      //  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        //return true;
    //}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nupur.phpdb_con.MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <EditText
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:ems="10"
           android:id="@+id/etUsername"
           android:layout_marginBottom="10px"

           android:hint="UserName"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="100px"
        android:hint="Password" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Login"
        android:layout_marginTop="400px"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nupur.phpdb_con">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

After Debugging Error:

```
E/Fail 1: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
E/Fail 2: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
E/Fail 3: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Error in Emulator:

> Invalid Ip Address

Comment: problem is here you pass two parameter and check for four parameter if($name == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == ''){
                echo 'please fill all values';
            }

Comment: nupur you are call network call in main thread mean you should call in background.

Comment: First you are not outputting JSON and the parsing will fail.

Comment: Have you Googled the individual errors, which are `NetworkOnMainThreadException`, etc?

Answer (score 0):

you cant echo string in php file and introduce as JSONObject in android.

all error and message must be in json array and just json array showed in php file .

i suggest this :

```
   <?php
        $host='localhost';
        $uname='amodbina0106';
        $pwd='Amodbina200';
        $db="kezin_king";
        $result = array();
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","amodbina0106","Amodbina200","kezin_king");
    if ($con->connect_error) {
   $result['status'] = false;
   $result['message'] = 'server lost';
        die(json_encode($result));
    } 


            $username = $_GET['username'];
            $password = $_GET['password'];
            $flag['code']=0;

            if($name == '' || $username == '' || $password == '' || $email == ''){
                $result['status'] = false;
                  $result['message'] = 'All field required';
            }
            else{



        $sql=mysql_query("insert into sample values('$id','$name') ",$con);

        if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))

        {
            $flag['code']=1;
              $result['status'] = true;
                  $result['message'] = 'hi';
        }

        print(json_encode($result));
        mysql_close($con);
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like below:
In insert method call asynctask like below:

```
new insertData().execute(namevaluepair);
```

and then code like below:

```
private class insertData extends AsyncTask<Arraylist<NameValuePair>, Void, String> { @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Arraylist<NameValuePair>... params) {
ArrayList<NameValuePair> namevaluepair=params[0];

//make http request here
    }}
```

for more information see this link you get idea how to implement it. [how to insert data in php using web service android](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/php-android-tutorial-part-1/)

Comment: Thanks.. Can you explain a little more where and how to AsyncTask<Arraylist<NameValuePair> and insertData class ?

Comment: @NupurBhagat  I have posted here one link see it helps you

Comment: I am getting error in getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);

Comment: @NupurBhagat have you create menu file? in resource

Comment: NO 

And the error is in 
id == R.id.action_settings)

Comment: @NupurBhagat  you want option menu? if you want then you need to create it else delete it . and if you want then see this link how to create option menu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=15

Comment: check in menu xml you have same id name which you given in xml

Comment: Can you suggest me that the way I have mentioned my URL is correct or not ?  HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://kezinking.com/SampleConLogin");

Comment: i think your url is wrong.SampleConLogin page is not available. there

Comment: ERROR:-

E/Fail 1: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
E/Fail 2: java.lang.NullPointerException: lock == null
E/Fail 3: org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of

Comment: @NupurBhagat you can just get response from server in doInBackground method  if you want to display that response then you have to do in postexecute method.

Comment: @NupurBhagat have you posted answer or updated code?

Answer (score 0):

MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.nupur.phpdb_con;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.List;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import static android.R.attr.id;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    EditText etUsername, etPassword;
    TextView Show;
    Button btnLogin;
    String username;
    String password;
    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    String line = null;
    int code;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    BufferedReader reader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
        Show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                insert(username,password);


                //Show.setText(etUsername.getText()+" "+etPassword.getText());



            }
        });


    }


    public void insert(final String username, final String password){
        class SendPostReqAsynTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String paramUsername=params[0];
                String paramPassword=params[1];
                //String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
               //String password = etPassword.getText().toString();
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs= new ArrayList<>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",username));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",password));

                try{
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                   // HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com");
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://kezinking.com/try.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    HttpResponse response= httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity entity= response.getEntity();
                    int i =response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

                    System.out.println(i);
                }catch(ClientProtocolException e){

                }catch (IOException e){

                }

                return "Success";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                TextView textViewResult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);
                textViewResult.setText("Inserted");
            }
        }
        SendPostReqAsynTask sendPostReqAsynTask=new SendPostReqAsynTask();
        sendPostReqAsynTask.execute(username,password);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
            }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.nupur.phpdb_con">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Android- activity_main.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.nupur.phpdb_con.MainActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <EditText
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:ems="10"
       android:id="@+id/etUsername"
       android:layout_marginBottom="10px"

       android:hint="UserName"/>
</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/etPassword"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_marginTop="100px"
        android:hint="Password" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250px"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/Login"
        android:layout_marginTop="400px"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginTop="600px"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

PHP file:-(try.php)

```
?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","amodbina0106","Amodbina200","kezin_king");
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>
<body>
<table style="width: 100%">
<?php
        $username=($_POST['username']);
    $password=($_POST['password']);
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `kezin_king`.`Test` (`Vendor_ID`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$password')");
$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `Test` WHERE 1");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
$vendor_id=$row['Vendor_ID'];
$user_name=$row['username'];
$password=$row['password'];
?>
    <tr>
    <th><?php echo $vendor_id; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $user_name; ?></th>
    <th><?php echo $password; ?></th>
  </tr>
 <?php }?> 
</table>
```

Here table name is Test and the database used is named as kezinking.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: It is the code for some organisation. So I can not share more information related to that. And thanks for guiding me.. Will not repeat the same.

Comment: Apache HTTP is deprecated library. I wouldn't necessarily recommend others use it when other alternatives exist